# Ionic: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources' (Some file crunching failed)

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic build command was working fine until I decided to add some custom splash screen and run the following command,

> ionic resources

Post that every time I run build command, I got below error while running build command,

> :mergeDebugResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 35126910): libpng error: Read
>   Error  FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
>
> Try:
>
> BUILD FAILED

So clearly, `ionic resources` command created some issues.

Please help!

Answer (score 15):

After going through multiple online resources, I found that `ionic resources` processes/optimizes the resultant PNG files.
Post that, when you run `ionic build android` command, Android build itself tries to work on already processed/optimized Splash screens but it doesn't work well and it reports an error.

So, the fix is to tell Android Build not to touch those PNG files at all and go ahead with what it is given. How to do that?

Put `cruncherEnabled = false` in `platforms\android\build.gradle` file as below,

> android {
>
> aaptOptions {
>            cruncherEnabled = false
>       }
>
> ...

Re-run the build and it goes through without any problem! :)

Comment: It didn't helped me not sure why. I placed mentioned code but it gives another weird error

Comment: I don't find the module level gradle file where I need to put this code.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the too long directory path. After I copied everything directly to d:\myapp, the "ionic cordova build android" command works as expected.

I found the solution in the ionic forum:

[Ionic Forum - Build Failed on existing project](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cli3-0-build-failed-on-an-existing-project/92704)

Answer (score 2):

For me it's because the path name is too long in Windows.
Renaming some folders to shorter names solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete `platforms\android\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-km`

Its work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Delete folder platform
Delete folder android and ios in folder "resources"
execute : ionic platform add android
after execute : ionic resources
and finaly execute : ionic build android

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Fixed by removing the whitespaces at my project's name folder.

Before:

```
/ionic project/myApp
```

After:

```
/ionicproject/myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you path small For example test/project/source/… change it to t/p/source…
It will work

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Android platform and give full permission to the public to the platform folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please change path of your project folder; previous path is too long.
Example:

```
d:projects/tfs/demos/ionic/projects/project_Name to projects/project_name folder
```

or

by using `subst` command in command prompt like below

```
 d:projects/tfs/demos/ionic/projects/project_Name folder :subst i: .
```

It will make an "i drive" in PC; open your project with that and build it.