# Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

i have some issues with ionic package build.
When i build my app i have this error :

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedReleaseLibrary
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2420Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2420Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2420Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2420Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2420Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42420Library
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseAssets
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.182 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/package/workspace/apps-ab71f554-17/cordova/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildRelease,-b,/home/package/workspace/apps-ab71f545-17/cordova/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

It happens after i added a plugin (toast) and make `cordova prepare`
I don't understand the logs and how to manage to fix the issue..

Someone have an ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, solved this by renaming mine folder, some paths are too big for windows, though, if you still have problems, I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545711/ionic-execution-failed-for-task-mergedebugresources-some-file-crunching-fai).

Answer (score -4):

It was just a problem of icon image...all of this for..that.

Comment: World have been better place, if you would have written what exactly is THIS & THAT in your answer.